# Table naming convention with Doctrine ORM

Tags: orm, doctrine, convention

Is there a convention for naming tables when using Doctrine ORM? I like to name tables with the plural but if there's a convention I want to stick to it.

So the table 'users' would be related to tables using the fk as the singular ('user_id').

Is there a best practice for this (using singular or plural table names) and if the latter, how does this apply to tables where the plural isn't a simple case of adding an 's'.

For example I currently have a table called 'categorys' instead of 'categories' to maintain the convention of adding 's'.

Is this a sensible approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used to use plural table names when using my own basic ORM but I switched over to singular table names when I started using symfony + Propel and now a little bit of Doctrine. The reason for this is for the class names because you want to create a *User* and not a *Users*.

With Doctrine, when it comes to collections or relations, you tell it what the alias should be:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/working-with-models/en

You'll see the a *User* can have many *Phonenumber* so a **foreignAlias** was setup in the YAML schema so it would be *Phonenumbers* effectively accessed via *$user->Phonenumbers*.

In your example you'll set the **foreignAlias** to be *Categories* while keeping the table and record named *Category*.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll wait a day or so to see if I get any other answers before marking you correct.

Answer (score 3):

The Doctrine convention is to use singular names for tables and models, as the first answerer explains, because logically you want methods like:

```
$user->Phonenumbers
```

... instead of:

```
$user->Phonenumberss
```

The definitions can be customised through Aliases.