# yet another Unknown record property / related component

Tags: model, doctrine, symfony1

I have this Symfony Recepciones class which is related to a Obras_Sociales_Recepciones class as my BaseRecepciones class claims:

```
   /* @method Recepciones          setRecepcionId()                       Sets the current record's "recepcion_id" value
    * @method Recepciones          setCuentaLaboratorioId()               Sets the current record's "cuenta_laboratorio_id" value
    * @method Recepciones          setCuentasLaboratorios()               Sets the current record's "Cuentas_Laboratorios" value
    * @method Recepciones          setObrasSocialesRecepciones()          Sets the current record's "Obras_Sociales_Recepciones" collection
    */
        abstract class BaseRecepciones extends sfDoctrineRecord
        {
            public function setTableDefinition()
            {
                $this->setTableName('Recepciones');
                $this->hasColumn('recepcion_id', 'integer', 4, array(
                     'type' => 'integer',
                     'fixed' => 0,
                     'unsigned' => true,
                     'primary' => true,
                     'autoincrement' => true,
                     'length' => 4,
                         ));
                $this->hasColumn('cuenta_laboratorio_id', 'integer', 4, array(
                     'type' => 'integer',
                     'fixed' => 0,
                     'unsigned' => true,
                     'primary' => false,
                     'notnull' => true,
                     'autoincrement' => false,
                     'length' => 4,
                     ));
            }
        
            public function setUp()
            {
                parent::setUp();
                $this->hasOne('Cuentas_Laboratorios', array(
                     'local' => 'cuenta_laboratorio_id',
                     'foreign' => 'cuenta_laboratorio_id'));
        
                $this->hasMany('Obras_Sociales_Recepciones', array(
                     'local' => 'recepcion_id',
                     'foreign' => 'recepcion_id'));
            }
        }
```

however... when I do this on an action

```
$recepcionPrueba = new Recepciones();
$recepcionPrueba->setObrasSocialesRecepciones($myObject);
```

it says:

> Unknown record property / related component "obras_sociales_recepciones" on "Recepciones"

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally discovered what happened, i hope it helps someone save the two or three days it took me to figure this out.

**Doctrine 1.2** accepts only two types of notations **for table names**

[CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) Or underscored_notation. Internally it recognizes any of them and its able to transform the former to the latter and vice-versa .

In my case if my **table name** was called "obras_sociales_recepciones" or "ObrasSocialesRecepciones" this error would've never ocurred.

the thing is that in Doctrine 1.2 you should **never use a mix of CamelCase AND underscore notation**, this is in my example Obras_Sociales_Recepciones, this absolutely confuses the ORM and you might recieve this strange error and never find out why!

Comment: The same problem was: table name was "amount_cur", but Doctrine wanted to get access to table "amount_CUR" but couldn't (table name was formed dynamically). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, as I'm a Propel user... would it help to move the `parent::setUp()` to the end of the setUp method? I am wondering if the parent does something with the relations, and is unable to if you define them after calling the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using plural names when choosing your model name (in your case, you should use `Recepcion`). Could you post the comment that is located just before the BaseRecepciones ? The good method name is supposed  to be in this comment, I guess it is something weird like `setObrasSocialesRecepcioness()` with 2 's'

Comment: Still you should really really switch to singular names. See this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100489/table-naming-convention-with-doctrine-orm and this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244615/naming-convention-singular-vs-plural-for-classes-describing-entities-in-php

Answer (score 0):

It's a one to many so you don't do:

```
$recepcionPrueba->setObrasSocialesRecepciones($myObject);
```

You do

```
$recepcionPrueba->addObrasSocialesRecepciones($myObject);
```

You call 'set' on a one-to-one.

Comment: sorry this isn't the solution, i just added the comments that appear before the function signature